# How to compute and plot KM curves and to compute the log–rank test in SAS

Tags: sas, data-analysis, survival-analysis

I am attempting to learn how to use SAS for survival analysis, but I am unsure exactly how to write the code to compute and plot KM curves/log rank tests. I already have the data set in question with me, but I am unsure how exactly to construct the code from here.

Answer (score 0):

[The LIFETEST Procedure](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetVersion=14.3&docsetTarget=statug_lifetest_overview.htm&locale=en) can do what you asked for. I would suggest exploring the [Examples](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetVersion=14.3&docsetTarget=statug_lifetest_examples.htm&locale=en) and [Videos](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetVersion=14.2&docsetTarget=statug_lifetest_videos.htm&locale=en) sections from the documentation.

A basic example of KM curves and log-rank test:

```
ods graphics on;

proc lifetest data=sashelp.BMT plots=survival(atrisk=0 to 2500 by 500);
   time T * Status(0);
   strata Group / test=logrank;
run;
```

If you have ODS HTML active and setup by default, then you should be able to see the output and images from the procedure. Log-rank p-value can be found in the table `Test of Equality over Strata`, `Pr > Chi-Square` column. Or you can fetch a p-value into a dataset via [ODS Table Names](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetVersion=14.3&docsetTarget=statug_lifetest_details73.htm&locale=en)